# Specifiying the primary key column when using DataSet.ReadXml()

Tags: c#, .net, xml, dataset

I receive a piece of XML that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ArrayOfPRODUCT>
    <PRODUCT>
        <SCHEDULE>
            <PRODUCT_CODE>100</PRODUCT_CODE>
            <FLAGS>4</FLAGS>
        </SCHEDULE>
        <MASTER>
            <PRODUCT_CODE>100</PRODUCT_CODE>
            <NAME>EXAMPLE</NAME>
        </MASTER>
        <INFO>
            <PRODUCT_CODE>100</PRODUCT_CODE>
            <DETAIL>DETAIL</DETAIL>
        </INFO>
    </PRODUCT>
</ArrayOfPRODUCT>
```

When I read it into a DataSet using ReadXml() it creates 4 DataTables:  PRODUCT, SCHEDULE, MASTER, INFO.  It also creates a primary key column on each DataTable called "PRODUCT_Id" which it fills with a sequential integer starting from zero.  Is there anyway to specify that the primary key column should be PRODUCT_CODE instead?

Comment: I'm not sure you can specify the PK in the XML itself; once read, however, are you able to manually set the key with something like this?: `productTable.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { productTable.Columns["PRODUCT_CODE "] };`

Comment: Then I would still have to manually delete the "fake" primary key from the other datatables and populate the inserted column with the correct data.  Is there a way to do with using XSD?

Comment: Ahh good call. I'm not sure, hope someone else answers!

Comment: I have a similar issue as the OP. I'm generating XML from DBFs not through a DataSet, but using a DataSet to read it back, and I'm getting these extra PK/FK fields. Is there something I can put in my XML in the first place to indicate the PK/FK fields, so I don't get the extra fields?